# Add textbox values to a listview in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, textbox

I've got two scenes (windows), main and secondary. 
In the secondary scene I've got a **name** `textbox` and a **description** `textbox`.
I want to write values into those two, then if I press the **create** `button` I want those to save to a list (or whatever is preferred) and get added as an **item** in the MainWindow `Listview`.
When i press the **item** in the listview it should display the name and description in two seperate `labels`/ `textblocks`..

I've tried  the following...

```
 public partial class SecondWindow : Window
    {
        List<string> nameList = new List<string>();
        List<string> contentList = new List<string>();
        public SecondWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        public class MyItem
        {
            public string Titel { get; set; }

            public string Text { get; set; }
        }

        private void Button_SaveAndReturn(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var nameInput = NameInput.Text;
            var textInput = TextInput.Text;
            MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow
            {
                DataContext = this
            };
            //Save information then close

            nameList.Add(nameInput);
            contentList.Add(textInput);

            mainWindow.listView.Items.Add(new MyItem { Titel=nameList.ToString(), Text=contentList.ToString() });

            this.Close();

        }
```

Am i even on the right trail or am i totally lost?

Comment: creating new MainWindow in SaveAndReturn (`MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow`) doesn't make sense. You should work with open instance of MainWindow.

Comment: There are many odd things here, but creating a new MainWindow is definitely wrong. Replace that by `var mainWindow = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;`.

Comment: You should have a view model class with a `public ObservableCollection<MyItem> Items` property. Assign a single instance of the view model class to the DataContext of both your windows. In MainWindow's XAML, bind it like `<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">` and in the secondary window, access it by `((ViewModel)DataContext).Items.Add(new MyItem { ... })`

Comment: This naming is bad practice: `var nameInput = NameInput.Text;`. it'd be better to call the string variable `name`. It's not an input, it's a string. You're creating unnecessary confusion, for you and for the VS autocomplete feature. Imagine if you and your brother had the same name, but his started with a lowercase 'f'.

Answer (score -1):

If I read you right here you need to change this line:

`mainWindow.listView.Items.Add(new MyItem { Title=nameList.ToString(), Text=contentList.ToString() });`

to

`mainWindow.listView.Items.Add(new MyItem { Title=nameInput, Text=textInput });`

Otherwise you're trying to add the `string` representation of `nameList` and `contentList`

Comment: @Hubii Why not? It is exactly what you wrote.

Comment: @Clemens Indeed many more things, but the main thing that he's doing wrong was this for the objective of posting the name and text input.

Comment: @Billy IMO the main error was to create a new MainWindow instance, instead of accessing the existing one.

Comment: My point was to access the existing window. To get access to the list.

Comment: @Clemens Understood, I got that now haha thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score -2):

You Need to do following Code:

```
mainWindow.listView.Items.Add(new MyItem() { Title=nameInput, Text=textInput });
```

Comment: No, you shouldn't do this. Instead, you should have a common view model for both windows.